# How to hide/unhide hidden node and update the connected edges in graph on click of connected edges

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, graph, vis.js

Graph-1

[image of Graph-1 click to preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZMzK.png)

- In the above graph there are 2 types of node , "Hidden Node" and "Non Hidden Node" which is connected to another node. The connection is call "edges" .
- "node" and "edges" data look likes :

```
let nodes = [
  { id: 1, node_name: "Node-1", is_hiddenable: false, hidden: false },
  { id: 2, node_name: "Node-2", is_hiddenable: false, hidden: false },
  { id: 3, node_name: "Node-3", is_hiddenable: true, hidden: false },
  { id: 4, node_name: "Node-4", is_hiddenable: true, hidden: false },
  { id: 5, node_name: "Node-5", is_hiddenable: true, hidden: false },
  { id: 6, node_name: "Node-6", is_hiddenable: false, hidden: false },
  { id: 7, node_name: "Node-7", is_hiddenable: false, hidden: false },
  { id: 8, node_name: "Node-8", is_hiddenable: true, hidden: false },
  { id: 9, node_name: "Node-9", is_hiddenable: true, hidden: false },
  { id: 10, node_name: "Node-10", is_hiddenable: true, hidden: false },
  { id: 11, node_name: "Node-11", is_hiddenable: false, hidden: false },
  { id: 12, node_name: "Node-12", is_hiddenable: false, hidden: false },
  { id: 13, node_name: "Node-13", is_hiddenable: false, hidden: false },
  { id: 14, node_name: "Node-14", is_hiddenable: true, hidden: false },
  { id: 15, node_name: "Node-15", is_hiddenable: false, hidden: false },
  { id: 16, node_name: "Node-16", is_hiddenable: false, hidden: false },
  { id: 17, node_name: "Node-17", is_hiddenable: true, hidden: false },
  { id: 17, node_name: "Node-18", is_hiddenable: true, hidden: false },
  { id: 17, node_name: "Node-19", is_hiddenable: false, hidden: false },
 ... 
 ...  // can be 'n' number
];
```

```
let edges = [
  { from: 1, to: 2, icon: "" },
  { from: 2, to: 3, icon: "-" },
  { from: 3, to: 4, icon: "" },
  { from: 4, to: 5, icon: "" },
  { from: 5, to: 6, icon: "" },
  { from: 2, to: 7, icon: "" },
  { from: 7, to: 8, icon: "-" },
  { from: 8, to: 9, icon: "" },
  { from: 9, to: 10, icon: "" },
  { from: 10, to: 11, icon: "" },
  { from: 2, to: 12, icon: "" },
  { from: 12, to: 16, icon: "" },
  { from: 16, to: 17, icon: "-" },
  { from: 17, to: 18, icon: "" },
  { from: 18, to: 19, icon: "" },
  { from: 12, to: 13, icon: "" },
  { from: 13, to: 14, icon: "-" },
  { from: 14, to: 15, icon: "" },
   ... 
   ...  // can be 'n' number
];
```

- Hidden Node can be identify, if "is_hiddenable" is true from node array.
- Hidden Node can be hide, if "hidden" is true from node array.
- icon (-/+) can be display, if "icon" is (-/+) from edges array.
- When click on (-) icon which is in between 'node 7' and 'node 8', The 'node 8 , node 9 and node 10' which are 'is_hiddenable', should be "hidden". And the edges { from: 10, to: 11, icon: "" } should update to { from: 7, to: 11, icon: "" }.like in graph 2

Graph-2
[image of Graph-2 click to preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDo56.png)

- When click on (+) icon which is in between 'node 7' and 'node 11', The 'node 8 , node 9 and node 10' which are 'is_hiddenable', should be display. And the edges { from: 7, to: 11, icon: "" } should update to { from: 10, to: 11, icon: "" }.like graph 3
- "node" and "edges" data for graph2 look likes :

```
let nodes = [
  { id: 1, node_name: "Node-1", is_hiddenable: false, hidden: false },
  { id: 2, node_name: "Node-2", is_hiddenable: false, hidden: false },
  { id: 3, node_name: "Node-3", is_hiddenable: true, hidden: true },
  { id: 4, node_name: "Node-4", is_hiddenable: true, hidden: true },
  { id: 5, node_name: "Node-5", is_hiddenable: true, hidden: true },
  { id: 6, node_name: "Node-6", is_hiddenable: false, hidden: false },
  { id: 7, node_name: "Node-7", is_hiddenable: false, hidden: false },
  { id: 8, node_name: "Node-8", is_hiddenable: true, hidden: true },
  { id: 9, node_name: "Node-9", is_hiddenable: true, hidden: true },
  { id: 10, node_name: "Node-10", is_hiddenable: true, hidden: true },
  { id: 11, node_name: "Node-11", is_hiddenable: false, hidden: false },
  { id: 12, node_name: "Node-12", is_hiddenable: false, hidden: false },
  { id: 13, node_name: "Node-13", is_hiddenable: false, hidden: false },
  { id: 14, node_name: "Node-14", is_hiddenable: true, hidden: true },
  { id: 15, node_name: "Node-15", is_hiddenable: false, hidden: false },
  { id: 16, node_name: "Node-16", is_hiddenable: false, hidden: false },
  { id: 17, node_name: "Node-17", is_hiddenable: true, hidden: true },
  { id: 17, node_name: "Node-18", is_hiddenable: true, hidden: true },
  { id: 17, node_name: "Node-19", is_hiddenable: false, hidden: false },
];
```

```
let edges = [
  { from: 1, to: 2, icon: "" },
  { from: 2, to: 3, icon: "+" },
  { from: 3, to: 4, icon: "" },
  { from: 4, to: 5, icon: "" },
  { from: 5, to: 6, icon: "" },
  { from: 2, to: 7, icon: "" },
  { from: 7, to: 8, icon: "+" },
  { from: 8, to: 9, icon: "" },
  { from: 9, to: 10, icon: "" },
  { from: 10, to: 11, icon: "" },
  { from: 2, to: 12, icon: "" },
  { from: 12, to: 16, icon: "" },
  { from: 16, to: 17, icon: "+" },
  { from: 17, to: 18, icon: "" },
  { from: 18, to: 19, icon: "" },
  { from: 12, to: 13, icon: "" },
  { from: 13, to: 14, icon: "+" },
  { from: 14, to: 15, icon: "" },
];
```

- Graph-3
  [image of Graph-3 click to preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGYr8.png)
- "node" and "edges" data for graph3 look likes :

```
let nodes = [
  { id: 1, node_name: "Node-1", is_hiddenable: false, hidden: false },
  { id: 2, node_name: "Node-2", is_hiddenable: false, hidden: false },
  { id: 3, node_name: "Node-3", is_hiddenable: true, hidden: false },
  { id: 4, node_name: "Node-4", is_hiddenable: true, hidden: false },
  { id: 5, node_name: "Node-5", is_hiddenable: true, hidden: false },
  { id: 6, node_name: "Node-6", is_hiddenable: false, hidden: false },
  { id: 7, node_name: "Node-7", is_hiddenable: false, hidden: false },
  { id: 8, node_name: "Node-8", is_hiddenable: true, hidden: true },
  { id: 9, node_name: "Node-9", is_hiddenable: true, hidden: true },
  { id: 10, node_name: "Node-10", is_hiddenable: true, hidden: true },
  { id: 11, node_name: "Node-11", is_hiddenable: false, hidden: false },
  { id: 12, node_name: "Node-12", is_hiddenable: false, hidden: false },
  { id: 13, node_name: "Node-13", is_hiddenable: false, hidden: false },
  { id: 14, node_name: "Node-14", is_hiddenable: true, hidden: true },
  { id: 15, node_name: "Node-15", is_hiddenable: false, hidden: false },
  { id: 16, node_name: "Node-16", is_hiddenable: false, hidden: false },
  { id: 17, node_name: "Node-17", is_hiddenable: true, hidden: true },
  { id: 17, node_name: "Node-18", is_hiddenable: true, hidden: true },
  { id: 17, node_name: "Node-19", is_hiddenable: false, hidden: false },
];
```

```
let edges = [
  { from: 1, to: 2, icon: "" },
  { from: 2, to: 3, icon: "-" },
  { from: 3, to: 4, icon: "" },
  { from: 4, to: 5, icon: "" },
  { from: 5, to: 6, icon: "" },
  { from: 2, to: 7, icon: "" },
  { from: 7, to: 8, icon: "+" },
  { from: 8, to: 9, icon: "" },
  { from: 9, to: 10, icon: "" },
  { from: 10, to: 11, icon: "" },
  { from: 2, to: 12, icon: "" },
  { from: 12, to: 16, icon: "" },
  { from: 16, to: 17, icon: "+" },
  { from: 17, to: 18, icon: "" },
  { from: 18, to: 19, icon: "" },
  { from: 12, to: 13, icon: "" },
  { from: 13, to: 14, icon: "+" },
  { from: 14, to: 15, icon: "" },
];
```

**My question ->**  how to to modify the node and edges data on click event. Lets take example of graph 3 where Node-7 and Node-11 have 3 another node which is hidden, on click of (+) icon all 3 hidden node should be display. like Node-2 to Node-6 . Data structure i have already share in graph 3 section. i want a function which is accept node id while on click event is fire and it should be able to find out the other "is_hiddenable" node which is connected in a series and update the value for "hidden" to unhide the node , at the same time it should update the edges data .

Comment: Where is your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To understand the behaviour of node and edges please have a look into https://visjs.org/  package.

Comment: @ravenspoint my question ->  how to to modify the node and edges data on click event. Lets take example of graph 3 where Node-7 and Node-11 have 3 another node which is hidden, on click of (+) icon all 3 hidden node should be display. like Node-2 to Node-6 . Data structure i have already share in graph 3 section. i want a function which is accept node id while on click event is fire and it should be able to find out the other "is_hiddenable" node which is connected in a series and update the value for "hidden" to unhide the node , at the same time it should update the edges data .

Comment: @trincot new account ??? what do you mean? i didn't get you.